# Countdown clock to add 14 days upon expiry

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, countdown, clock

I'm trying to make the countdown clock add 14 days once it expires. I'm using Keith Wood's plugin. How can i make the until in the restartCountdown to add to the actual value of the row instead of adding to the echo?

Here is my html code:

```
 <div class="expiry_wrap">
        <p>Offer Ends:</p>
             <div id="defaultCountdown">
             </div> </div>
```

And here is the script code:

```
<?php } ?>

 <?php if($row['expiry']){

 $ex = explode('/', $row['expiry']); ?> <script>
     var newYear = new Date();
     newYear = new Date(<?php echo $ex[2]; ?>, <?php echo $ex[0]; ?> - 1, <?php echo $ex[1]; ?>); 
     $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: newYear, onExpiry: restartCountdown, alwaysExpire: true});



  function restartCountdown() {  
               $('#defaultCountdown').countdown('option', {onExpiry: restartCountdown; until: new Date(<?php echo $ex[2]; ?>, <?php echo $ex[0]; ?> - 1, <?php echo $ex[1]; ?> + 14)});


 </script>
```

Comment: So you have an expiration date in the database, and want to add 14 days to it, when it is expired?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly right.